# Binding nested JSON data in SAPUI5 XML view

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I am trying to bind data from a nested JSON file in my SAPUI5 application. The view is in the XML format.

Here is the snippet from my JSON file:

```json
{
    "Departments": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Name": "Транспортный цех 1",
            "Count": 35,
            "Address": "Корпус 1, Этаж 7",
            "Logo": "image/manager1.jpg",
            "Employees": [
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Базенков",
                    "FirstName": "Андрей",
                    "MiddleName": "Анатольевич"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Базенков",
                    "FirstName": "Андрей",
                    "MiddleName": "Анатольевич"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Name": "Транспортный цех 2",
            "Count": 35,
            "Address": "Корпус 1, Этаж 7",
            "Logo": "image/manager1.jpg",
            "Employees": [
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Базенков",
                    "FirstName": "Андрей",
                    "MiddleName": "Анатольевич"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Базенков",
                    "FirstName": "Андрей",
                    "MiddleName": "Анатольевич"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am loading the JSON file in my controller and then binding the data "Address" and "Name" in my XML view as follows:

```xml
<List id="list1" items="{path:'/Departments'}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem icon="{Logo}" type="Active" press="onListItemPress" number="{Count}" title="{Name}">
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute text="{Address}" />    
            </attributes>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

However when I tried binding the nested data "FirstName" or "LastName" like this I am not able to bind it.

```
text="{Employees/LastName}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employees is an array.

1. You can pick one entry and use `{Employees/0/LastName}` if you like.
2. You can also use a formatter function to merge the employees to a string:

View:

```
<ObjectAttribute text="{path: 'Employees', formatter: '.formatEmployees'}"/>
```

Controller:

```js
formatEmployees: function(aEmployees){
  return aEmployees.map(function(employee){ return employee.LastName + ", " +  employee.FirstName; }).join("; ");
}
```

3. You can use a list-control like sap.m.ListBox or sap.m.Tokenizer and bind the items to the Employees array.

Comment: Thanks, 
Also, I used text="{Employees/0/LastName}"
and it is working now.

Comment: @schnoedel : Employees from view return complete employees array. So in ur above code i hope it returns only first item always. I hope this is not correct answer

Comment: @PraveenGopal You are right: My first suggestion is displaying the last name of the first employee in the array. The other employees will not be displayed. My second and third suggestions however will display all employees in the array. It seems that the author of the question choose my first suggestion for whatever reason. Perhaps the first entry in the employees array is always in charge of the department... Can you please explain what you think is not correct in my answer so that i can fix it?

Comment: @schnoedel : I am wrong actually. As u explained ur answer is perfect.